# mod_rewrite rule won't work when matching GET parameters

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^wiki/search[.php]*?q=(.*)$ /wiki/search/$1 [R]
```

in an attempt to rewrite the format /wiki/search?q=search_query to /wiki/search/search_query which is then rewritten using

```
RewriteRule ^wiki/search/(.*)$ /wikisearch.php?id=$1 [L]
```

However .. so long as I have the `?q=` in the first rule it simply will not work and instead just leaves me with a 404 error. :(
Why is this? Can I not use GET parameters in rewrite rules or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [read in the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), `RewriteRule` applies only to the "URL-path", not including the query string:

> On the first RewriteRule, it is matched against the (%-decoded) URL-path (or file-path, depending on the context) of the request. Subsequent patterns are matched against the output of the last matching RewriteRule.

To match on the query string you can use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), and later reference the match and groups in the following rewrite rule with `%0` and `%1`...`%9`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bq=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^wiki/search(?:\.php)?$ /wiki/search/%1
```

On the other hand, what you are doing seems pretty ugly and I'd advice you from avoiding such useless external redirects (`[R]`). Rewrite to the desired URL without external redirects, or better handle all query string modifications in your application/script.